# Are these as efficient as each other?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Temp Table #X (it contains 100k records) is used later in a stored procedure and needs to be indexed.

Are these two as efficient as each other:

- Create #x
- Fill #x with data
- create an index on #x

...or does changing the order impact efficiency:

- Create #x
- create an index on #x
- Fill #x with data

Comment: Did you try them and compare?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Unfortunately I've not taught myself how to analyse execution plans yet - I assume that would be the scientific way of comparing?

Comment: Well you could also perform the poor man's comparison, and the one that usually matters most to your end users - do they take the same amount of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill the table first, then create the index. Doing it the other way means every insert has to update both the table and the index.